# Sharepoint Workflow Error

Tags: workflow

I have created two lists. I wanted that when ever a user creates an Item in List1, the same item to be automatically created in List 2.

I have configured a SharePoint 2013 Workflow for the same. When admin creates a list, the workflow works fine. But when a Member creates, the workflow throws following error in two stages.

**Phase 1** :

> Suspend this workflow
>
> Activity in progress
>
> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP NotFound to
>   http://etheem/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'a0f94a5f-128e-41ec-b9f2-f65aa815be03')/Items(19)
>   Correlation Id: 4660ef44-a8f2-fdbb-9346-876122bb60f0 Instance Id:
>   d67989ea-8a33-4da9-806f-a22ad31899c4 Retry now

**Phase 2** :

> Resume this workflow
>
> RequestorId: 4660ef44-a8f2-fdbb-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["28"],"SPRequestGuid":["4660ef44-a8f2-fdbb-a10a-063e3a4cd1c2"],"request-id":["4660ef44-a8f2-fdbb-a10a-063e3a4cd1c2"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Fri,
>   03 Jul 2015 05:46:30
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Is member has edit access on 2nd list?

Comment: What access does member have on site, list 1 and list 2 ? Also can member manually create item in list 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the App step feature include the workflow  and check once.. if it works fine  with App Step then the users having a permission issue against  the list  for performing the operations

please check the  below link

[Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you examining the Stack Trace carefully you will see HTTP 404 error. Which means you gets *not found*  error. I believe you don't have sufficient access to the resource.

Have you broken the security inheritance of the list ? Try whether you can see the list item by login to the particular site or app ( in your case item id 19)