# SPD 2013 workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I created workflows with SPD 2013, it work well first time. I deleted the workflow Manager Configuration, then reConfigured It. but my workflows Are Canceled. with this error :

> RequestorId: 824a5c9f-aa85-a889-a75b-aac14c7bae32. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["26"],"SPRequestGuid":["e663037d-18bf-4872-968c-63079c7d4abf"],"request-id":["e663037d-18bf-4872-968c-63079c7d4abf"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4957"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Tue,
>   12 Jun 2018 12:03:45
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Please how i can resolve that?

Comment: what about uncheck automatically update the workflow status like in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2015/06/18/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-designer-workflow-in-suspended-or-canceled-state/. Or have the writes to the hidden workflow history list change due to the configuration? SPD>All Files>Lists: potential initiators should have contribute rights like in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148112/sharepoint-workflow-error

Comment: Delete those old workflows and create new ones and deploy them again.

Comment: Check SharePoint logs. check your error exception in that. What is it saying?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the User from System Account to simple User. Now The workflow is Started but the Error was changed :

> RequestorId: 824a5c9f-aa85-a889-a75b-aac14c7bae32. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Item does
>   not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."}}}
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["21"],"SPRequestGuid":["98a20b8a-c54e-4cec-9ad2-e1a346283b9e"],"request-id":["98a20b8a-c54e-4cec-9ad2-e1a346283b9e"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4957"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Tue,
>   12 Jun 2018 15:32:54
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine`1.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)